# How to compare 2 collections and fetch matched field data in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a two collection as given below.

Collection 1: **List**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b618589d6edcc135c1aee0a"),
"name" : "ABC",
"special" : "Golmal",
"dim" : "2122",
}
```

Collection 2: **Data**

Document 1:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b6023d9589ff6bfb5dd75d7"),
"date" : "2018/08/13",
"special" : "Golmal",
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b602447589ff6bfb5dd7606"),
"date" : "2018/08/13",
"special" : "Godman",
}
```

Here I want compare both the collection and if `"special":"Golmal"` of Collection 1 is present in Collection 2 documents I want to display/fetch all the related date from Collection 1 document.

I have tried `aggregate` & `$lookup` as below

```
getAvailableList(): Promise<any> {
    return this._mongoUtility.Db
        .then(db => {
            let list= db.collection('list');
            let data= db.collection('data');           
            list.aggregate([{$lookup:
                {
                    from: data,
                    localField: "special",
                    foreignField: "special",
                    as: "matches"
                }
            },
                {
                    $match: { "matches": { $ne: [{}] } }
                }
            ]);
            return Promise.resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject({message: 'Not found', err: err});
        });
}
```

But I'm getting null.

I have also tied by using `.find` & `forEach` as below

```
 let abc = [];
            list.find({}).toArray()
                .then(arr => {
                    arr.forEach(obj1 => {
                        data.find({special: obj1.special}).toArray()
                            .then(secondArr => {
                                console.log(secondArr);
                                if (secondArr.length > 0) {
                                    abc.push(obj1);
                                }
                            });
                    });
                });
            return Promise.resolve();
```

But no result. I need value in JSON format. As MongoDB dont have joins. Is there any ways to crack it?

Comment: the localField and the foreignField should be the `special` for both the collections

Comment: That was a mistake. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I changed my way of doing that query by not using `forEach` and its working for me.

I come across `$in` in `find` in mongoDB website. Here's the answer

```
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        this._mongoUtility.Db
            .then(db => {
                let list= db.collection('List');
                let data= db.collection('Data');

                data.find({}).toArray()
                    .then(arr => {
                        let maps = arr.map(data => data.special);
                        list.find({special: {$in: maps}}).toArray()
                            .then(secondArr => {
                                res(secondArr);
                            });
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return rej({message: 'Not found', err: err});
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As of MongoDB 3.2, joins become possible.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Comment: I have not used JOINS. I got the solution.